Renaming multiple columns that contain regular expressions in R
I have a data frame with the following column headers:
"x_y_z, a_b_c, a_b_d, a_b_e, a_b_f" etc.
I want to remove the "a_b_" part from the column names that starts with "a_b_" so that only the last character remains.
How can I do this, without having to rename each column name individually ?
I tried using the dplyr::rename_with() function with the substr() and tidyselect::starts_with() function, but I could not get the code to work:
rename_with(df, substr(df, 5,5), starts_with(a_b\_)) 
With this I tried to truncate the column names that start with "a_b_", but it does not work.
I used the "R for Data Science" book to get help on this.

names(dfrm) <- gsub(“a_b_” , “”, names(dfrm) )

dplyr::rename_with() takes a function as the second argument. You can define a function with function(x) ... or with the anonymous function shorthand \(x) ....
tidyselect::starts_with() takes a character as its argumemt. Enclose a_b_ in quotes to make it a character.
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  x_y_z = 1:3,
  a_b_c = 1:3,
  a_b_d = 1:3
)

rename_with(df, \(x) substr(x, 5,5), starts_with("a_b_"))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   x_y_z     c     d
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     2     2     2
#> 3     3     3     3

# Using regex you could do something like this:

rename_with(
  df, 
  \(x) str_extract(x, "a_b_([a-z])", group = 1), 
  starts_with("a_b_")
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   x_y_z     c     d
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     2     2     2
#> 3     3     3     3

# Or:

rename_with(
  df, 
  \(x) str_extract(x, "[a-z]$"), 
  starts_with("a_b_")
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   x_y_z     c     d
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     2     2     2
#> 3     3     3     3

